# Equivalent WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("next").GetAttribute("value")); c# in METRO APP

Tags: c#, .net, webview, microsoft-metro

I need to make a program that gets the collection of divs from a page loaded in a webview, I have the code what do that but is in C# .net , and I need to do this in Metro app with c#.

Can any Help me?

That is my code in c# .net:

On Load_Complete

```
private void explorador_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.vbuscar & (this.explorador.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete))
        {
            try
            {
                int num = Convert.ToInt32(this.explorador.Document.GetElementById("next").GetAttribute("value"));
                int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(this.explorador.Document.GetElementById("show").GetAttribute("value"));
                while ((num - num2) >= 0)
                {
                    num = Convert.ToInt32(this.explorador.Document.GetElementById("next").GetAttribute("value"));
                    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(this.explorador.Document.GetElementById("show").GetAttribute("value"));
                    this.explorador.Document.InvokeScript("toggle");
                }
                this.hilo_mp3s = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.iMostrar_Mp3));
                this.hilo_mp3s.IsBackground = true;
                this.hilo_mp3s.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A ocurrido un error al intentar navegar en internet...\nLa interaccion de la aplicacion con internet no se ha terminado por compleo", "Error al buscar en internet", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                this.vbuscar = false;
                this.cargando.Detener(100);
            }
        }
    }
```

La Funcion Mostrar MP3

```
    private void iMostrar_Mp3()
    {
        this.linternet.Invoke(new MethodInvoker (delegate {
            HtmlElementCollection elementsByTagName = this.explorador.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            this.linternet.EliminarTodos();
            foreach (HtmlElement element in elementsByTagName)
            {
                if (element.Id == "song_html")
                {
                    HtmlElementCollection elements2 = element.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                    string innerText = "";
                    foreach (HtmlElement element2 in elements2)
                    {
                        if (element2.GetAttribute("className") == "left")
                        {
                            innerText = element2.InnerText;
                        }
                        if (element2.Id == "right_song")
                        {
                            HtmlElement element3 = element2.GetElementsByTagName("div")[0];
                            string nombre = element3.InnerText;
                            try
                            {
                                HtmlElement element4 = element2.GetElementsByTagName("div")[2].GetElementsByTagName("div")[1].GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                                string album = innerText.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', '-');
                                Uri uri = new Uri(element4.GetAttribute("href"));
                                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(uri.LocalPath);
                                this.linternet.AgregarItem(-777.0, nombre, element4.GetAttribute("href"), info.Directory.Name, album, "--++", 1, "", Resources.iinternetItem, 300);
                                itemlista itemlista = (itemlista) this.lista.Elementos[this.lista.Elementos.Count];
                                itemlista.Imagen = Resources.iinternetItem;
                                itemlista.Imagenplay = Resources.ilista1;
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            this.vbuscar = false;
            this.cargando.Detener(100);
        }));
    }
```

**I just want to know how I do that in a C# Metro app.**

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] args = { "document.GetElementsByTagName('div')" }

MywebView.InvokeScript("myinvoke", args);
```

Check this one....